# Attaching events via jQuery to Angular element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm working on an AngularJS site where we also have the full jQuery library running.

In this site, I have an element on a page:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="refresh()" title="Refresh">Refresh</a>
```

If I open up the JavaScript console and enter this:

```
$('a[title="Refresh"]').click(function() {
    alert("click");
});
```

I see the "click" alert the first time I click the link. The second time I click the link, however, I get no "click" alert.

Furthermore, if instead of `$('a[title="Refresh"]').click(...)`, I enter this into the console:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[title="Refresh"]', function () {
    alert("live click");
});
```

I don't see an alert of "live click" at all.

What's going on here? How come my `$('body').on('click'...` doesn't alert "live click"? I need to use `$('body').on('click'...` because the DOM elements on the page (i.e. the refresh link) don't exist at the time the code adding the "click" handler fires.

Is there an imperative way to accomplish a jQuery "live" event handler in Angular—a means that isn't declarative (besides adding my event handler code into the scope's `refresh()` that's wired via `ng-click`?

Comment: Have you tried using `$.noConflict();`?

Comment: Why would you no want to add it to $scope.refresh()?

Comment: How about keeping a variable in $scope.refresh that refers to a function, and if it is not null you call it. That way you could extend refresh on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the event in a directive

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Refresh" refresh>Refresh</a>

app.directive('refresh',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attr) {
            element.on('click',function() {
                alert("live click");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a directive and add it to body (or any other element), optionally passing in a selector to use for binding live click events on:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" live-click="a[title='Refresh']">
    ...

app.directive('liveClick', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var selector = attrs.liveClick || '*';
            elem.on('click', selector, function (evt) {
                var target = evt.target;
                var nextID = elem.children().length;
                elem.append($('<button id="btn' + nextID + '">Button ' + 
                              nextID + '</button>'));
                alert('Clicked button #' + target.id + '.');
            });
            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                elem.off('click');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/L2czx/)**.